# how do I properly create an sql query that joins four tables with a common key

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables, that have a key in common.
three of the four tables are small subsets of the fourth,(master).
I want to join the tables such that only the output only contains records from the master table, that are on any of other fourth:

as an example:
[image]

My end result should look like this:

[image]

My problem is that joins I'm using, are giving me only the records that are common to all tables.
or records that are common to only one of the tables and the master.

Any help on formulating the correct join would be awesome!

Comment: have you tried LEFT JOIN to the tables that may NOT have a matching ID key in the underlying tables.  Start with your MASTER and LEFT JOIN to the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three left joins will produce the result you want. For example:

```
select a.*, b.color, c.size, d.weight
from a
left join b on b.id = a.id
left join c on c.id = a.id
left join d on d.id = a.id
where b.id is not null or c.id is not null or d.id is not null
```

**EDIT**: Added WHERE clause above as requested.

Comment: Maybe he wants a IFNULL(column, '') too.
He wants the rows to be empty if null.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully explained the problem. What I getting are all the matching records from "b","c","d" ( which is what I want ), but I'm also getting all the a records from "a", that don't match "b" and "c" and  "d"

Comment: @C0ppert0p See edit.

Comment: MY MAN!!! You saved my bacon with that update! It worked beautifully.